# How to share audio as voice message via Whatsapp from web (Universal Link)?

Tags: javascript, html, share, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have some audio files (mp3) hosted in a server, and I'd like to add some web functionality to share them via WhatsApp as an audio message.

I've been able to share texts succesfully with the following code:

```
whatsapp://send?text="TEXT_TO_SHARE"
```

but if I put the mp3 url where the "TEXT_TO_SHARE" part, it is just linking it as plain text (the url), instead of as audio (with its Play button and so).

I've tried with several file formats (.mpeg, .ogg), but same failed result.

Reading this [documentation](https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app), it seems that the only parameter available after the `what sap://send?` part is `text`, although I was expecting something like audio or media. I've seen that sharing audios is be possible with the Business API ["framework"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/media#upload), but I'd like to do it from a simple HTML. I think that the concept is named as `Universal Link` ([doc](https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app)) but I haven't found any way to build that universal link for audio messages.

Please, do you know if it's possible to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you're linking to is focused on iphone topics. Share Extension, Introduced in iOS 8.0 is described there and sounds like a solution for what you're trying to do. But this will send an audio message **from users' phone number to you**, not the other way around.

WhatsApp Business API (WABA) allows you to send any media files from your company account to WhatsApp users.

WABA requires some developer effort, but there are also **different WhatsApp API based solutions** that make this whole process a lot easier.

One of them is [**get.chat** WhatsApp Business Team Inbox & WhatsApp Integration API](https://get.chat/) which makes this whole process a lot easier to you. Plus, it will enable the WABA access to non-technical people in your company, too!

I am a co-founder and CTO so feel free to reach out if you want to know more about our solution. Here is also a link to [the docs](https://docs.get.chat/) if you're interested in learning more by yourself.